# HTML 5 Video scaling

Tags: html, css

I have a background video that I have got to scale based on the size of the browser/device. Im now trying to figure how to make it constantly go to the top of my page. For some reason when it scales down it pushes itself down.

The only way to adjust it is to make the height of the class .landing_video smaller which would then move it back to the top position, or I can make the top of #landingbg to a negative value. Are these the only ways to adjust the position to constantly stay at the top position?

HTML

```
        <div id="landbg">
            <video loop muted autoplay class="landing_video">
                <source src="video/landingbg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
/*----Landing Page Styling----*/
#landbg{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

.landing_video{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The video looks fine at 1920x1080 its when it scales down to the device scale it almost looks like a form of padding. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a fiddle to illustrate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/md7fqtvh/2/

Comment: Why are all your `L` letters capitalised? It looks odd. Otherwise, why are you defining all four coordinates for your `fixed` position? That gives unpredictable behaviour. Could you throw this in a SO snippet so we can see what you mean? And are you complaining about the fact that the black space is added and the video is centered by the browser? If so, remove the `height: 100%` property from your video as videos will only be proportionally scaled to fit the `video` frame by most (all?) browsers. That way the `height` will be automatic in proportion.

Comment: @somethinghere I have added a js fiddle, so you can see what the problem is when you scale it......ummm im not sure about the L's thing they not caps on my side. Ill try messing with removing some of the things you suggested

Comment: Cool it seems that your heigh suggestion fixed the problem. It does become difficult once you reach tablet scale. But that I would disable anyways. Any reason why removing that height does that?

Comment: It's because a video _always_ scales proportionally. I assume it is because the actual video is in the `source` element, and that one cannot be styled. The `source` will always fit the video proportionally in the center of the `video` container. If you remove the height, the video container is simply proportional to the width and the proportions of the video (aka 16:9), so there are no 'borders'.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help man. If you want to post the fix below I can upvote as the answer. But otherwise thanks again

Comment: Heres an interesting tidbit I found: http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit - could help! I am not going to post an answer as I find I have some knowledge but it's all from experience, and I can't really refer to any documentation describing it, and I won't go out of my way to find it :) There are people on SO that know those specs and are better at answering these things :)

Comment: cool! thanks man will take a look